# How to have correct working directory paths in R Studio dynamically?

Tags: r, dynamic, path, rstudio

I am trying to have some code that has a nested structure - e.g. one script calls another using source().

As I have a complex file/folder structure and I want the code to be reproducible on other machines, I want to use dynamic paths (so not the paths on my computer). I thought of this strategy - have a fixed folder structure, and then allow the scripts to 'realise where they are' in this folder structure.

But I encountered an issue that I have no idea the reason behind.
This is a reproducible example. Think of this folder structure:

```
├── parent folder: file "test.R"
│   ├── ChildRMD (subfolder)
│   │   ├── "test2.R"
```

Is this is confusing, basically there is a parent folder with file "test.R", and then there is a subfolder in this parent folder called "ChildRMD". In "ChildRMD" there is another R script "test2.R".

These are the contents of the files.

1. test.r

```
# Get the path of the current R script
current_path <- dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path)

setwd(current_path)

print(paste('Path in test is,',current_path))

#source(paste(current_path,'/ChildRMD/test2.R',sep=''))
```

2. test2.R

```
# Get the path of the current R script
current_path <- dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path)

setwd(current_path)

print(paste('Path in test2 is,',current_path))
```

The output if I run each script individually (keep in mind I commented the 'source' line in test.R, is:

1. test.r

```
"Path in test is, /Users/admin/Documents/temp"
```

2. test2.r

```
"Path in test2 is, /Users/admin/Documents/temp/ChildRMD"
```

Looks all good. Basicaly the files realized where they are using the dirname() function. So if I uncomment out the first line (source), so the test.R looks like:

```
# Get the path of the current R script
current_path <- dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path)

setwd(current_path)

print(paste('Path in test is,',current_path))

source(paste(current_path,'/ChildRMD/test2.R',sep=''))
```

And I just run test.R (which would run both scripts, as I am calling test2.R inside test.R), I get:

```
[1] "Path in test is, /Users/admin/Documents/temp"
[1] "Path in test2 is, /Users/admin/Documents/temp"
```

Not what I would have expected, which would be:

```
[1] "Path in test is, /Users/admin/Documents/temp"
[1] "Path in test2 is, /Users/admin/Documents/temp/ChildRMD"
```

This is basically a small example of my issue. Calling this source() command seems to affect how the files represent their working directories, and can't tell why.

Comment: I haven't looked at this carefully, but the `here` package might help you.

Comment: Looks very good indeed! Seems you can have one main parent directory that doesn't change regardless of what happens with the files, exactly what I needed I think... thank you so much!

Comment: Feel free to post some version of this conversation as an answer to your own question (you may have to wait a little while).

Comment: Good idea! I'll try to see if I can get it to work with ```here``` and will reply to my question if it works..thanks!

Comment: Just added it!:)

Answer (score 1):

Someone suggested to use the package `here`, which works very well!

If I set the main directory using `library(here)`, then by calling `here()` I have the output:

```
"/Users/admin/Documents/temp"
```

Regardless of where I am in the hierarchy.
Then, the path of `test.R` will always be given by `here('test.R')` and the path of `test2.R` given by `here('ChildRMD','test2.R')`. Then, I can modify the `test.R` script like this:

1. test.R

```
# Get the path of the current R script

print(paste('Path in test is,',here('test.R')))

source(here('ChildRMD','test2.R'))
```

2. test2.R

```
# Get the path of the current R script

print(paste('Path in test2 is,',here('ChildRMD','test2.R')))
```

If I run just test.R I have as output:

```
[1] "Path in test is, /Users/admin/Documents/temp/test.R"
[1] "Path in test2 is, /Users/admin/Documents/temp/ChildRMD/test2.R"
```

If anyone has a more elegant condition, feel free to add here.